# A question regarding Cramér's proof on prime gaps under the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis, prime-gaps

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime. Assuming the Riemann hypothesis, Harald Cramér proves that $p_n-p_{n-1}\le C(\sqrt p_n \log p_n)$ for sufficiently large $n$. Is there a value known for the constant $C$ that works? In Cramer's original paper ([On the order of magnitude of the difference of consecutive prime numbers](https://eudml.org/doc/205441), Acta Arithmetica 2 26-46) Cramér makes $C=5\lambda$, but I was unable to give an upper bound value to $\lambda$ from a first reading of the paper. Perhaps one of you knows?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[On the Riemann hypothesis and the difference between primes](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793042115500426) by Adrian W. Dudek states the result (Theorem 3, at least in [the arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6417)) that any $C>1$ works (for $n$ sufficiently large).

Comment: Carneiro, Milinovich, and Soundararajan improved this to $C=21/25$, and it holds for all $n\geq 4$.

Comment: Is there any conjecture for what the sharp constant actually is -- e.g. one predicted by standard random models?

Comment: @KevinCasto $0$

Comment: @KevinCasto Cramer's model predicts that prime gaps are *much* smaller than $O(\sqrt{p_n}\log p_n)$, indeed they are expected to be $O((\log p_n)^2)$. This is know as the [Cramer's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture).

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to give some additional remarks to Will Sawin's answer and the associated comments.

[Carneiro, Milinovich, and Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04122.pdf) certainly have the best result in literature (as far as I'm aware). They showed that $C=21/25$ for sufficiently large $n$, but only $C=22/25$ for $p_n>3$.

It's still an open and interesting question (that I've been thinking about) to determine the lowest value of $C$ without assuming anything beyond the Riemann Hypothesis. Certainly, if one assumes Montgomery's pair correlation (or something stronger), then it's possible to take $C$ arbitrarily small as $n\to\infty$. See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01475582) by Goldston and Heath-Brown for instance.